# MYSQL - How can I get this left join to work?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    food_types ft
        LEFT JOIN
    member_has_food_types mhft ON (ft.food_id = mhft.food_id)
 WHERE mhft.member_id = 3230
```

Okay, so here are the database tables

Food Types:

```
        FOOD_ID  | FOOD_TYPE | STATE
        1          APPLE       1
        2          ORANGE      1
        3          BANANA      1
        4          CAKE        1
        5          BACON       1
```

member_has_food_types:

```
        FOOD_ID  | MEMBER_ID 
        1          3230
        2          3230
        4          3230
        5          3230
```

So because member_has_food_types does not contain a number 3 food, then the report comes back like:

```
        FOOD_ID  | FOOD_TYPE | STATE | FOOD_ID  | MEMBER_ID 
        1          APPLE       1        1           3230    
        2          ORANGE      1        2           3230
        4          CAKE        1        4           3230
        5          BACON       1        5           3230
```

But I want it to include a NULL like this

```
        FOOD_ID  | FOOD_TYPE | STATE | FOOD_ID  | MEMBER_ID 
        1          APPLE       1        1           3230    
        2          ORANGE      1        2           3230
        3          BANANA      1        NULL        NULL
        4          CAKE        1        4           3230
        5          BACON       1        5           3230
```

My understanding is its not showing a NULL for those fields, because im joining on food_id. So is there any clever way I can get around this with a sub query??

Comment: `mhft.competency_id` does not appear to exist??

Comment: Sorry I meant to say food_id, I had to rename the existing columns and tables to fake columns, as I cannot post our real DB tables on here :) I edited it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the filter to the join

```
 SELECT * FROM food_types ft
 LEFT JOIN member_has_food_types mhft ON ft.food_id = mhft.food_id  
 AND mhft.member_id = 3230
```

Comment: Will this produce the NULL row for BANANAS?